# What is the best way to extract method?

Tags: python, lambda

The code snippet is what I want to do. Previously I use a different version of my code. But it is out of joint according to Python coding guidelines because I was assigned my lambda function to a variable. It was an obvious violation. Here is my violator code:

```
my_dict = {
    'first_name': 'Jimmy Floyd',
    'last_name': 'Hasselbaink'
}

db_data = {}

def create_info(db_data, data):
    split_join = lambda field: '_'.join(data.get(field).split()) if field in data else None
    name = split_join('name')
    first_name = split_join('first_name')
    last_name = split_join('last_name')
    code = '_'.join(filter(None, [name, first_name, last_name])).lower()
    db_data['code'] = code
    return db_data
```

Then I have extracted my split_join variable to a method. The code is below:

```
my_dict = {
    'first_name': 'Jimmy Floyd',
    'last_name': 'Hasselbaink'
}

db_data = {}

def split_join(data, field):
    return '_'.join(data.get(field).split()) if field in data else None

def create_info(db_data, data):
    name = split_join(data, 'name')
    first_name = split_join(data, 'first_name')
    last_name = split_join(data, 'last_name')
    code = '_'.join(filter(None, [name, first_name, last_name])).lower()
    db_data['code'] = code
    return db_data

new_db_data = create_info(db_data, my_dict)
print(new_db_data)
```

I have forced into writing split_join method in three times. Is there any way to prevent this situation?

Comment: Just to check, you do know that `data` is not being copied or modified when you pass it to `split_join`, right? It's just a reference, so no extra data is created nor is the original modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db_data = {}

def create_info(db_data, …):
    …
    return db_data

new_db_data = create_info(db_data, …)
```

This feels plain wrong. Either your `create_info` function mutates data, or it generates some; but not both. Judging by the name, your function should create the dictionary it returns:

```
def create_info(data):
    …
    code = …
    return {'code': code}

db_data = create_info(my_dict)
print(db_data)
```

---

If you want to avoid passing `data` as a parameter to `split_join` and not use a `lambda` altogether, you can still define a nested function which will capture the needed variables:

```
def create_info(data):
    def split_join(field):
        return '_'.join(data.get(field).split()) if field in data else None
    …
    code = …
    return {'code': code}

db_data = create_info(my_dict)
print(db_data)
```

---

You can avoid calling `split_join` several times by using `map`:

```
def create_info(data):
    def split_join(field):
        return '_'.join(data.get(field).split()) if field in data else None
    name, first_name, last_name = map(split_join, ('name', 'first_name', 'last_name'))
    code = '_'.join(filter(None, [name, first_name, last_name])).lower()
    return {'code': code}

db_data = create_info(my_dict)
print(db_data)
```

What is interesting with that, is that you can feed the result of `map` directly to the `filter`:

```
def create_info(data):
    def split_join(field):
        return '_'.join(data.get(field).split()) if field in data else None

    code = '_'.join(
            filter(
                None,
                map(split_join, ('name', 'first_name', 'last_name'))
            )
    )
    return {'code': code.lower()}

db_data = create_info(my_dict)
print(db_data)
```

---

Last improvement would be to not rely on `None` being generated when there is no data available, but `''` instead, since you’re only manipulating strings:

```
def create_info(data):
    def split_join(field):
        return '_'.join(data.get(field, '').split())

    code = '_'.join(
            filter(
                bool,
                map(split_join, ('name', 'first_name', 'last_name'))
            )
    )
    return {'code': code.lower()}

db_data = create_info(my_dict)
print(db_data)
```

---

**Update** According to your comment:

You can obviously remove the need for a nested function by switching back to a `lambda`:

```
def create_info(data):
    code = '_'.join(
            filter(
                bool,
                map(lambda field: '_'.join(data.get(field, '').split()),
                    ('name', 'first_name', 'last_name')
                )
            )
    )
    return {'code': code.lower()}

db_data = create_info(my_dict)
print(db_data)
```

But readability is becoming worse. In any case, it is often recommended to convert `map` + `lambda` into an explicit list-comprehension or generator expression instead. I’m choosing the generator expression here because we won't need an intermediate list:

```
def create_info(data):
    code = '_'.join(
            filter(
                bool, (
                    '_'.join(data.get(field, '').split())
                    for field in ('name', 'first_name', 'last_name')
                )
            )
    )
    return {'code': code.lower()}

db_data = create_info(my_dict)
print(db_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this code?

````py
import unittest


db_data = {}
name_info = {"first_name": "Jimmy Floyd", "last_name": "Hasselbaink"}


def create_info(db_data, name_info):
    def _join_underbar(key):
        if key in name_info:
            return "_".join(name_info[key].split())

    name_info_list_with_join_underbar = [_join_underbar(field) for field in name_info]

    db_data["code"] = "_".join(name_info_list_with_join_underbar).lower()
    return db_data


class TestCreateInfo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_create_info(self):
        db_data, name_info = {}, {"first_name": "Jimmy Floyd", "last_name": "Hasselbaink"}
        actual = create_info(db_data, name_info)
        self.assertEqual(actual["code"], "jimmy_floyd_hasselbaink")
```
````